# How to get real time log from external process Python 2

Tags: python, subprocess

In your Document folder create a folder `temp`:

`/My Documents/temp`

Save these few lines as `worker.py` Python scripts:

```
import time 
from datetime import datetime
for i in range(10):
    print '%s...working on iteration %s' % (datetime.now(), i)
    time.sleep(0.2) 
print '\nCompleted!\n'
```

Save the code below as `caller.py`:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['python', 'worker.py']
stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
print stdout
```

**(Please note that both Python scripts were saved in to the same folder).**

Now using the OS X Terminal or Windows CMD window change the current directory to the folder you created:

`cd /My Documents/temp`

Now run:

`python caller.py`

The process takes 2 seconds to complete. When completed it prints out the entire progress log all at once:

```
2018-01-20 07:52:14.399679...working on iteration 0
...
2018-01-20 07:52:16.216237...working on iteration 9
Completed!
```

Instead of getting the log printed (all at once after the process has been already completed), I would like the have a real-time progress update. I would like to get every printed line from the process at the same moment it occured.
So, when I run `python worker.py`command it will give me line by line update happening in a real time. How to achieve it?

Comment: Don't know to answer your question but consider using IPC instead to communicate: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a real-time feed from the subprocess you can use this code in the caller.py

```
import time 
import subprocess

# Start worker process
p = subprocess.Popen(['python', '-u', 'worker.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# Loop forever
while True:

    # Get new line value
    l = p.stdout.readline()

    # Stop looping if the child process has terminated
    if p.poll() is not None:
        break

    # Print the line
    print l
```

Note the *-u* in the subprocess.Popen, you need unbuffered stdout.
https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u

With readline() you are reading a single line per time from the subprocess output. Be aware when the subprocess prints '\nCompleted!\n' you will read it in three loops.
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

In the example, the loop will run until the subprocess will terminate.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll

Comment: How can your solution work with the example posted in a question (two python scripts with the first being `worker.py` and the second being `caller.py`)? Where and how should your `follow()` function be used? Please clarify.

Comment: @alphanumeric Updated the answer with the correct code